# How do find common items and get their individual user values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Users, Movies, Ratings. How do I create a MySQL query that returns a list of movies that two specified users have seen, giving both information about the movie and both users seperate rating?

I have created a [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13ca38) with some example databases

**Expected result for users A=1 and B=2:**
Both have seen The Shining and Interstellar so they each have one entry with movie info plus both users ID and ratings are in the results. Other movies and ratings are not included.

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
| id | UserA | UserB | RatingA | RatingB | Name         |
+----+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
|  1 |     1 |     2 |      10 |       9 | The Shining  |
|  2 |     1 |     2 |       9 |       7 | Interstellar |
+----+-------+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Have you hear about [**JOIN**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) ??

Comment: Yes of course. I want a list of movies which both users have rated.

Comment: So what have you try? What part you have problem with? I could wrote it for you. But then you wont learn much.

Comment: I've managed to make a query that returns the common ratings, but I don't know how to get each users ID and rating to it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13ca38/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Self JOIN, use alias to difference between each user..

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13ca38/18)

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*, m.Name
FROM rating u1
JOIN rating u2
  ON u1.MovieID = u2.movieID
 AND u1.UserID = 1
 AND u2.UserID = 2
JOIN Movies m
  ON u1.MovieID = m.ID
```

Comment: Thanks you! So much simpler than what I was trying to do! I guess it's the self join that I haven't used before.

Comment: No problem, just remember next time post what you have tried. So we can focus on what is the problem instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Yeah I should have added it directly (its in the comments on the question), but it was not working at all so I figured it cleaner to start fresh.